# Swift 3 - UIView does not always display its content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIViewController (Main Menu) that is displayed after my other UIViewController (Loading Screen) finishes downloading/syncing data from the web. My Main Menu is having problems as it doesn't always display all the UIButtons that are on the view when it shows up! There is an inconsistancy, 1 out of every 10 times the Main Menu loads, all the UIButtons will appear.

Here's how the view should look: [image: Correct View]

Here's how the view usually shows up: [image: How it shows up]

I can put my finger where the UIButtons should be and move my finger away and they'll appear. I can also tap where they should be and my segues will still trigger, but the UIButtons dont just automatically show up. It looks like [image: This]

I attempted to add a MainMenuView.setNeedsDisplay() to the ViewDidLoad function and it didn't help. I also created a test UIButton on the view that triggers a MainMenuView.setNeedsDisplay() command but the hidden UIButtons remain hidden.

If I leave the screen idle for 30 or so seconds, all the UIButtons will randomly appear without me having to manually make them appear.

The Main Menu view is normal and all UIButtons are visible if I segue to it from any part of the app aside from my Loading Screen.

Edit: Main Menu Code - (references are Strong)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: References
    @IBOutlet var btnGasManifolds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnAirCompressors: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnVacuumPumps: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnUnitConversion: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnCFMCalculator: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var mainMenuView: UIView!

    var userData = [NSManagedObject]()

    // MARK: Functions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var name = String()
        for duserData in userData {
            name = duserData.value(forKey: "nameFull") as! String
        }
        print("Main Menu\n->\(name)")
        backgroundSetup()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mainMenuView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnTest(_ sender: Any) {
        mainMenuView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
        if segue.identifier == "settingsSegue" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! SettingsViewController
            destination.userData = userData
        }
    }

    // Background Setup
    func backgroundSetup() {
        let background = UIImage(named: "Data Screens")

        var imageView : UIImageView!
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        imageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = background
        imageView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you post your code for this view. Thanks.

Comment: @dfd I added the code. I was experimenting with the mainMenuView.setNeedsDisplay, so you can disregard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which creates and shows the buttons after fetching the data from server needs to run on Main UI thread. If the code is running the background thread it will not properly display the UI elements and will take some time or manual scroll before showing the controls.

Run the code on Dispatch main queue.

Comment: Before I posted this question, I attempted to trigger the performSegue function from my loading screen with a DispatchQueue.Main.async (I also tried sync), and it didn't fix my problem. The UIButtons are not created programmatically, but on the storyboard inside xCode. How do I go about putting the code that creates and shows the buttons on the main queue? Do I create the buttons programmatically and run it in the main queue?

Comment: OK. I'm not really sure if I'm seeing enough code yet, but here's my take. First, **something** is obviously causing time (which is missing here unless you've tromped on your own code with all the setNeedDisplay and other calls to the view lifecycle and segue). My guess is if you strip out all that code and **still** see issues (you probably will) we're talking db fetching. If so, then it's something you need to code against **before** the segue. Set this in your first VC (maybe throwing up an alert for the user), then set up your second VC properties, and the segue.

Comment: I ended up getting my UI Elements to show. I had to run loading screen code like this `DispatchQueue.main.async { datasyncfunction() ; seguefunction() }`

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   //do some work   
})
```

OR
Override one of the methods from ViewWillLayoutSubviews and ViewDidLayoutSubviews accordingly and run your code in these methods.

Comment: Where do I go about placing the dispatch code? What content do I put inside of it? My UIButtons are not created programmatically, if that makes a difference. Do I need to create them programmatically inside of the main queue?